# An error occurred when Casbin created a database table

Tags: go, go-gorm, casbin

Excuse me, I'm creating a Casbin adapter with `golang`,`postgresql` and `gorm`, using

```
adapter, err := gormadapter.NewAdapterByDB(db)
```

automatically creates the table. When I run the program for the first time, everything works fine, but when I run the program again, I get an error.

```
pq: got 1 parameters but the statement requires 0
```

At the moment we can know that it is the error of `a.db.AutoMigrate(t)`.
Tables are created automatically, and I don't understand why AutoMigrate fails. Please help me answer it

When I delete the Table from DataBase, run program again , everything works fine, but the second run is the same error

Comment: The information you provided is not enough to reproduce the problem. Please add more details

Comment: this Github issue might be helpful https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/5409

Comment: The problem is still not solved， but I found another way to create Casbin adapter. 
I don't use `gormadapter "github.com/casbin/gorm-adapter/v3"`， I use `pgadapter "github.com/casbin/casbin-pg-adapter"` to create Casbin adapter.